How to apply gevent monkey patch using django-admin with huey?
I have a django app that uses huey. I want to enable the greenlet worker type for the huey consumer.
Running django-admin run_huey logs this message and tasks do not run.
I managed to run the huey consumer successfully with the greenlet worker type by using the manage.py and apply the monkey patching there as documented here
Is it possible to achieve the same with django-admin? Do I have to create a custom manage command that applies monkey patching before the huey consumer runs?
